# Flutter `SocketException: HTTP connection timed out` sometimes when app start

Tags: android, flutter, http, dart, networking

I have a Flutter application and it makes some HTTP requests to my server. However, once in a while (not sure when, but I have seen it several times a day), when I open my app, the HTTP requests that happen during the first few seconds **all** report the error of `SocketException: HTTP connection timed out` (the source code that throws this seems to [be here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/40766bd74266af011e410614179f054ac5db4226/sdk/lib/_http/http_impl.dart#L2482-L2484)). However, after the first few seconds, other HTTP requests will succeed.

I have tried hard reproducing it but failed. Usually this bug happens, when I put my phone there for some time and then open the app (but it is not a thing for sure; also in many cases such behavior will not trigger the bug). If the bug happens, and I close the app and reopen it immediately, it will run very well and the bug will not happen again.

I have also used Wireshark to try to look at the network packages. However, when I setup the environment as "my app (in my phone) connects to my computer with development server using wifi and http", that bug seems to never appear again. Only with the production environment "my app (in my phone) connects to a server in the cloud using https" that this bug happens. But in that case I cannot use Wireshark to look into the packages.

I know I do not provide a reproducible sample, but I really cannot find out any clues. I even cannot stably reproduce it :(

I would truly appreciate it for any suggestions!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this issue in one of my initial projects, which usually happens with HTTP package, I'll recommend you to try this package:

https://pub.dev/packages/dio

And if you are an android developer then you may know it is the best combination to use dio with retrofit

https://pub.dev/packages/retrofit

Comment: Actually, I use dio as well. but its request also fails when other requests using raw http Client fails :(